# Replication On Different Number of Columns

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I have two schema with the same table name:
Example:schema_a.dbo.item having column 'a','b','c','d' where 'a' is primary key
and schema_b.dbo.item having column 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g' where 'a' is primary key.
schema_a.dbo.item table is my publisher database,i am using transnational replication
where schema_b.dbo.item table is my subscriber.Is it possible to still replicate data using transnational replication?
data type are same among common column between schema table.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Not,yet it's a live server replicating 15 database with it,but haven't tried this type of replication.I am expecting experts advice whether it can be done or not.

Comment: Ok i tried and it worked.Thanks